how to calculate total cost for an ad in Google Ads data in BigQuery
Goal:
I am trying to calculate the total spend (cost) of an ad from by Google Ads data that is in BigQuery
Problem:
The output of my BQ SQL does not match the output I see in Google Ads reports
Example:
In BigQuery, I grab the metrics_cost_micros from AdStats table and divide it by 1m for the time period. This tells me for 'Ad 1' the total cost is $3,625.76 and avg CPC $1.21
SELECT 
  a.ad_group_ad_ad_name,
  SUM(metrics_cost_micros)/ 1000000 AS total_spend,
  AVG(metrics_cost_micros)/ 1000000 AS avg_daily_spend,
  MAX(metrics_cost_micros)/ 1000000 AS max_spend
FROM `[project].google_ads.p_ads_AdStats_xxx` ast
LEFT JOIN `[project].google_ads.p_ads_Ad_xxx` a 
  ON ast.ad_group_ad_ad_id = a.ad_group_ad_ad_id
WHERE a.ad_group_ad_ad_name = "Ad 1"
GROUP BY ALL

However, in Google Ads reporting tool, the same ad in the same timeframe has a total cost of $107.53 and avg CPC of $0.38
I thought currency conversion might be an issue, but it doesn't account for the discrepancy

Have you made sure the time zones are the same?
